# Javascript - global variables undefind

Tags: javascript, variables, global

i have a problem that i cant understand the problem is that in my views dir global vars are all defined and dont have any problems but when i make a dir inside the views and put my files inside it all the global vars turns undefined i have tried to search and see if anyone have my problem in here but i didnt find anything  **note: my problem is not with scopes**

this is my global vars app.js code

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});
```

```html
This is my ejs(js and html)
Note: this code is working realy well in the views dir but in any dir in the views dir it undefind

NOTE: THIS IS EJS NOT HTML

<h4 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-remove-vertical text-light">
<%= currentUser.username %></h4>
```

pls help i rly need help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please tag the question with the MVC framework you're using